# Multiple Relationships From One Node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Is it possible to create a node and multiple relationships from it in one cypher statement? So if I have node `A` the relationship would be something like:

```
A -> [HAS] -> B & C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like:

```
create (a:Node {name:"A"})-[:HAS]->(b:Node {name:"B"}),
(a)-[:HAS]->(c:Node {name:"C"})
```

The above `create` statement will generate the following nodes & relationships:

[image: Generated nodes & relationships]

Comment: Thanks you very much! Works like a charm :D

Comment: Hi @RyanFalzon you are welcome! If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.